# Is there a way to remove all tags from a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

With 1.13's new `/tag` command there seems to be no way remove *all* tags from a Player, only specific tags.

```
/tag <targets> remove <name>
```

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tag

Comment: Do you need to know what possible tags? (As in a clear command that clears everything without you knowing what is already previously tagged, or could be tagged?)

Comment: Just clears Any and All Tags

Comment: May I please know what tags you are trying to remove and I'll gladly answer this question.

Comment: I made it so that players can "buy" buffs by simply tagging them for a buff which a Repeating Command Block automatically buffs said player with said tag.

Some of the specific names of the custom tags are:
permBuffFRes, 
permBuffJmp, 
permBuffStr, 
permBuffSpd, 
permBuffRes, 

and many more too many to list (hence why I'm asking how to remove all of them at the same time in one command.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there's also the way of manually inputting all tags that you want to remove and tagging yourself for removal of all Tags to remove all tags that you want to remove before removing the tag of removal of tags functioning as basically a clear tag

Basically:

```
tag @p add removeTags
```

then, a Repeating command block detects if any player has a tag and also has the tag of removal

```
tag @a[tag=removeTag] remove Tag1
tag @a[tag=removeTag] remove Tag2
tag @a[tag=removeTag] remove Tag3
tag @a[tag=removeTag] remove removeTag
```

in a chain command block

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. For entities you could set their `Tags` NBT tag to be an empty list, but you can't modify NBT of players. The `tag` command doesn't allow wildcards for tags, only for entities.